Transiesta, not converging with semi-conductor electrodes
Hello transiesta users.
I am trying to calculate the I-V curves of 2D blue phosphorene(electrodes are made of the same material the semiconductor 2D blue phosphorene ) by using transiesta code.
First I was facing the problem of convergence by increasing the bias more than 0V,to fix this problem I played on the eta value wich I increased it to 0.01 istead than 0.0001, of course by increasing slightly the voltage steps.
After fixing the problem of convergence I noticed that the charge dQ is not 0 or close to zero it gave me a negative values like -6.978E+0,-1.441E+1 as shown below,I think based on these values the physics behind our study will not be correct.


Do you propose any solution for this problem?
By the way I already increased the screening layers between the electrode and the scattering region.

+1. Welcome to our community. Please, add the output in a code format instead of image (edit your post, add the output text, mark as code block).

In addition to the comment by Prof. Camps, I think it will help if you add a bit of detail regarding your input files (also as a code block) and the parameters / figures eta and dQ.

Transiesta relies on the fact that the electrode Fermi-levels are well-defined.
One cannot simply use semi-conductors as electrodes for NEGF calculations.
The problem arises because of the screening layers towards the electrodes.
E.g. consider a metal, it will screen of any defect quite fast, no more than 1 nm (system dependent!) away the electrons there won't even know there is a defect.
This is drastically different for a semi-conductor. There are no electrons left to screen off the defect. Hence there will be some effective field very far away due to the defect. And this is what is causing problems.
This is also explained in the manual.
The bad screening length makes it hard to set the Fermi-level of the electrodes since it can be arbitrarily set.
Basically you can't do the calculation you want like that. Not even at 0 V!
